# how to add a -fluid to a class with subname with sass

Tags: css, sass

i have this code in scss:

```
.container.home-tec.air-50{ 
    width: 95%; <br>
  padding-right: 15px; 
  padding-left: 15px; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  margin-left: auto; 
}
```

and i want the container to become container-fluid i have tried doing this:

```
$grid__bp-md: 768; 
.container.home-tec.air-50 { 
  max-width: 950px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  &-fluid { 
    margin: 0; 
    max-width: 100%; 
  } 
}
```

but in the end it remains like this: 
`container home-tec air-50-fluid` 
and all i want is: 
`container-fluid home-tec air-50` 
I m changing a wordpress page and i cant get html, can someone help? pls

Comment: Why is this flagged with "php" and "wordpress" and "sass"? This is a css question. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this helpful?

```
//SCSS
.container {
  &.home-tec.air-50 {
    max-width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  &-fluid {
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```
//Generated output (CSS)
.container.home-tec.air-50 {
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container-fluid {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```